# When accessing JHipster web app deployed on AWS beanstalk i get page: Your request cannot be processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When accessing JHipster web app deployed on AWS beanstalk I get page: `Your request cannot be processed`

I went over the existing reported issues on 'Your request cannot be processed' and i'm familiar with the resolution to run yarn.

It solved the issue locally, but when i deploy the JHipster web app war to AWS beanstalk, I get `Your request cannot be processed` response.

On the browser console, I found this message:

> 2fixurl.js:148 A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://linkhelp.clients.google.com/tbproxy/lh/wm?sourceid=wm&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeliverypal.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com%2F&hl=en&site=deliverypal.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com&error=http404&js=true, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
>
> ```
>     ib @ fixurl.js:148
>     Ce @ fixurl.js:149
>     (anonymous) @ fixurl.js:149'
> ```

Comment: What is your question? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I updated the title and body hopefully the issue is more clear now @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Thanks for editing @JohnRotenstein!